# Implications of the falseness of ABC conjecture

Tags: number-theory

Some of the consequences of the proof of **ABC Conjecture** are listed at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture

But if the conjecture turns out to be false what are its immediate consequences. And how does it affect the Beal Conjecture specifically.

Comment: A post like this is not really on topic for Math Stack Exchange, unfortunately.

Comment: In all humility I am wondering why not. I would argue that the immediate (known) mathematical consequences of the refutation of ABC conjecture is a valid question.

Comment: @TheoryQuest1 Perhaps what Cameron is alluding to is the help center's section on [types of questions to avoid asking](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." and, "[avoid] asking an open-ended, hypothetical question[s]: 'What if ______ happened?'"

Comment: It would not necessarily affect the Beal conjecture. By abc we only would know that there are finitely many coprime solutions. Beals conjecture says much more. Goldfeld says: "The remarkable thing
about the abc Conjecture is that it provides a way of reformulating
an infinite number of Diophantine problems and,
if it is true, of solving them."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best answer to this broad question is a recommendation. Namely to read the beautiful slides of [Waldschmidt](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwilsLWIutHnAhXknFwKHSjpDagQFjAKegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebusers.imj-prg.fr%2F~michel.waldschmidt%2Farticles%2Fpdf%2FabcEn.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0zr9EWFw_raOFEEtRaAlO7) for the wealth of consequences of $abc$. If false, this would be "lost". Still, the consequences could be true nevertheless (and are true, like FLT).

The other consequences of $abc$ not holding (besides losing so much consequences) are more difficult to describe. Then, for example, our understanding of elliptic curves (concerning the conductor, Szpiro's conjecture) would be false and Grothendieck's anabelian geometry not like expected (but I am not qualified to make precise statements here).

Comment: thanks a lot. Going through them.